# If $D'$ is a Noetherian $D$ module, then $D'$ is Noetherian as $D'$ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

I am studying the Proposition: Let $D$ be a Dedekind domain, $F$ its field of fractions, $E$ a finite dimensional extension field of $F$ and $D'$ the subring of $E$ of $D$ integral elements. Assume that $E/F$ is a finite separable field extension. Then $D'$ is a finitely generated $D$-module.

I have to show that $D'$ is Noetherian. It is clear from the Proposition that $D'$ is a Noetherian $D$ module. Why does it follow that $D'$ is Noetherian as $D'$ module?

Would you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: By scalar restriction, every $D'$-module is a $D$-module.

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg Thank you for your hint. So, since $D'$ is a $D'$ module, then $D'$ is a $D$ module and since $D'$ is a Noetherian $D$ module, then $D'$ module is a submodule of $D$ module and hence it is Nloetherian. Thus $D'$ is Noetherian as $D'$ module. Am I right?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you write after "then". My idea was more to prove, for example, the ascending chain condition for $D'$-submodules of $D'$ with that above hint.

Comment: If you probably edit your question and make it more understandable probably we can help you out. For me its a bit confusing what you are asking at the moment. For instance, you already know how to prove the proposition and the question is why $D'$ is noetherian as a $D'$-module, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every ideal of $D'$ is a $D$-submodule of $D'$, so if you have an ascending chain

$$I_1 \subseteq I_2 \subseteq \cdots$$

of ideals of $D'$, then it must terminate, because $D'$ is a Noetherian $D$-module.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, here is a sort of answer that you might like.

**Hints and facts**:

Because of the situation we have (which is really good in fact since the rings we have very *good* structures) the extension $D \subset D^{\prime}$ is integral, and $D$ is normal (as Dedekind domain is integrally closed). Hence we have very good correspondence between the prime ideals inside $D$ and primes inside $D^{\prime}$ respectively. Commonly in bibliography are referred as **Going Down, Going up** theorems (if you haven't heart them so far is a good chance to meet them because are one of the basics in commutative algebra, otherwise skip them) and you can find them in *any* book of commutative algebra, included this online notes http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/main.pdf (page 89).
So what this correspondence establishes, is that prime ideals in $D^{\prime}$ are giving prime ideals in $D$ and vice versa. In a Dedekind domain every ideal is a product of primes, and in *commutative case only*, finite product of finitely generated ideals is finitely generated ideal, so in order to prove your question it's enough to restrict our attention to prime ideals in $D^{\prime}$, since the latter is Dedekind domain too (is integrally closed by its definition, Noetherian domain and since our extension $D \subset D^{\prime}$ is integral has Krull dimension $1$ as well). Now from all the above facts your question maybe is more clear now. Instead of writing out explicitly the proof (which is kind of long-scale in fact) it's good I think to work it out alone and if you have any queries please do let me know!

The above result you can find it out as **Krull-Akizuki** theorem in many textbooks. (also a short proof can be found on wiki article too)

Comment: Disclaimer, I misread your question in the first place and made complicate a very simple argument because of that. I won't delete my answer because isn't wrong what I ve written and probably contains some sort of knowledge that you weren't aware of. Also gives in fully generality the idea of your question. Cheers!